# How to change Yii Error Handler on the fly?

Tags: php, error-handling, yii

In Yii's config.php we have this statement which declares which Controller is the default and only-one Error-Handler within the application:

```
'errorHandler' => array(
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
),
```

So, I need to have an `actionError()` under my **SiteController**, to get the errors previewed in my site, but this is not what I really need.

I am trying to change the `Yii::app()->errorHandler->errorAction` on the fly, throughout my custom-controllers who extend the base `CController` (Yii's base controller).

Till now, I have tried something like this:

```
<?php

class AdminController extends CController {

    public $layout = '//layouts/admin';

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        Yii::app()->errorHandler->errorAction = '/admin/error';
    }

}
```

But gives no results, nor hope. Note that I also have this URL configuration:

```
'/admin' => '/admin/home',
'/admin/<controller:\w+>' => '/admin/<controller>',
'/admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '/admin/<controller>/<action>',
'/admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '/admin/<controller>/<action>',
```

And this means I have a whole **Controllers-Views** group named **admin**, and they are stored in following directories:

- protected/controllers/admin
- protected/views/admin

So by that logic, I have **ErrorController** in both: **admin** and **controllers root**, and by the same structure in the **views directory**.

That's what I have tried, and I really appreciate help, so thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should try this :

```
Yii::app()->setComponents(array(
    'errorHandler'=>array(
        'errorAction'=>'/admin/error'
    )
));
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#setComponents-detail

Comment: Do you know how to pass over a page title to the errorAction?